# Getting SyntaxError:c:/Users/Dhivya/.cordova/blackberry10.json unexpected Token error

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am developing project in Blackberry10 webworks.While running project using webworks SDK 2.0 BETA version in z10 device showing following error
Module.js:485
SyntaxError:c:/Users//.cordova/blackberry10.json unexpected Token

Help me out with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the json file is not corrupted. Mine is as follows:

```
{
"targets": {
    "Z30-2fffffff": {
        "ip": "169.254.0.1",
        "pin": "2fffffff",
        "type": "device"
    },
    "All Touch [1280x768]-ffff926a": {
        "ip": "172.16.12.128",
        "pin": "ffff926a",
        "type": "emulator"
    }
  }
}
```

This file will only affect the deployment so you are technically still able to build and then deploy using a command line tool.

Try also running the command manually using the command prompt (cmd on windows):

```
cordova emulate blackberry10 --devicepass <password>
```

Instead of "cordova" you should be able to run the "webworks" command
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/v2_0/deploy_to_a_simulator.html#kba1376494743113

Failing that make sure you upgrade to the latest version of WebWorks 2.0 (https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/download/).
Before you do so rename the file to something like blackberry10_bak.json so that a new one can be created from scratch.